# Linking multiple columns of one table to a single column in another table - Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

This is a qlik sense question.

I have the below table (project_task) for the tasks and subtasks.
[image]

The tree looks something like this (X,Y,Z,A,D are root nodes):

[image]

I have a table(task_tree_format) like this in database, which depicts the project tasks in depth format:

[image]

I want to place the name1, name2 and name 3 in pivot table so that it appears in hierarchical format(with expand and collapse buttons) in my Qlik Sense sheet.

My requirement is -

***When task 'B' (NAME2 column) is selected in pivot table, it should perform the operation based on the same 'Task Name' in project_task table.
Eg.. If I select Task 'B' in pivot table, it should trigger the 'Task Name' B in project_task table.
In short, I want to associate NAME1, NAME2 and NAME3 columns with the 'Task Name' column in project_task.***

I request your help on how to proceed with this in the load data editor.

Appreciate your help regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest to put the task I'd of the parent task instead of the task name of the parent task in the third column.

Comment: yeah, I have that column with me.

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot table cannot be used to represent a tree of unlimited depth. You are trying to use the wrong tool. What you need is a recursive algorithm that will read the table and spit out to the tree using the desired indentation and aggregation on another sheet.

That said, you would be better off using MS project or any proper project management tool rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I understand that. Pivot table is not the aptest data structure for a dynamic tree.Since Qlik sense does not have any widget which can show a dynamic tree, I am limiting the pivot table to maximum depth and using the last table to get a tree. If you could guide me on how to link the NAME1,NAME2,NAME3 column(last picture) to task_name column (1st picture), that would really help me.